# Optimize a MySQL query that selects rows from another table as columns and uses a HAVING clause

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to speed up a query that uses a join and group by to get rows from a table as columns in another table and that also uses a having clause.

I have the following two tables:

Users:

```
id  name
1   bob
2   joe
3   paul
```

Possessions:

```
id  user_id type_id type        name
1   1       1       car         honda
2   1       2       computer    mac
3   2       1       car         toyota
4   2       2       computer    pc
5   2       3       phone       htc
6   3       1       car         toyota
7   3       2       computer    pc
8   3       3       phone       samsung
```

I'm using the following query:

```
select
  p.user_id,
  u.name,
  max(case when p.type=1 then p.name end) as car,
  max(case when p.type=2 then p.name end) as computer,
  max(case when p.type=3 then p.name end) as phone
from
  possesions p inner join users u
  on p.user_id=u.id
group by
  p.user_id,
  u.name
having
  car='toyota'
```

to get this as output:

```
user_id name    car     computer    phone
2       joe     toyota  pc          htc
3       paul    toyota  pc          samsung
```

There is a decent amount of data - about 75k users, 200k possesions, and 25 different possession types. The query is taking ~5 seconds. When I do an explain on the query I get this:

```
id  select_type table      type   possible_keys          key                    key_len    ref             rows     Extra
1   SIMPLE      users      index  (NULL)                 PRIMARY                4          (NULL)          77453    Using index
1   SIMPLE      possesions ref    FK_possessions_users   FK_possessions_users   4          mydb.users.id   1
```

I have indexes on all the id columns. Just wondering if there's anything else I can do to speed this up. If I remove the HAVING clause it becomes lighting quick of course. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
select u.id, u.name,
       max(case when p.type = 1 then p.name end) as car,
       max(case when p.type = 2 then p.name end) as computer,
       max(case when p.type = 3 then p.name end) as phone
from users u join
     possesions p
     on p.user_id = u.id
group by u.id, u.name
having car = 'toyota';
```

MySQL offers basically no opportunities for optimizing aggregation queries.  You can change this to a `join` version to see if that works.  So, assuming that each type appears at most once:

```
select u.id, u.name, pc.name as car, pcomp.name as computer, pp.name as phone
from users u join
     possesions pc
     on pc.user_id = u.id and
        pc.type = 1 and pc.name = 'toyota' left join
     possessions pcomp
     on pcomp.user_id = u.id and pcomp.type = 2 left join
     possessions pp
     on pp.user_id = u.id and pp.type = 3;
```

For this, you want an index on `pc(user_id, type, name)`.

Note:  the savings for the query are by avoiding the aggregation with the `group by`.  If there are multiple names for a given type, then you might need to aggregate anyway.